# Backup folder using batch or powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I am learning C# AND Java and I often create small projects and programs in these languages. Usually my source code is at C:......\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyProject or C:......\Eclipse\Projects\MyProject.

I often get to a point where the code is partially working and while trying to add a new feature I end up breaking the working code. It is frustrating to fix all the changes and get back to the old state and takes a long time just to go back to where I came from.

I was wondering if you could help me write a batch (or Win PowerShell?) script to back up my source folders to  a D:\Backup\SourceCode\CSharp\MyProject and D:\Backup\SourceCode\Java\MyProject. And place the script on my desktop so that i can run it time to time whne i have good working code.

Or if there are any other solutions to this problem that you might be using are also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A real version control system is far better. I would recommend 
[GIT](http://git-scm.com/)

Here is a batch example to do what you want:

```
REM Delete backup directory
if exist D:\Backup\Code\*.* rd D:\Backup\Code /s /q

REM Create/recreate backup directory
mkdir D:\Backup\Code

REM Copy files/folders
xcopy "C:\SourceCodeFolder" /e /i /y D:\Backup\Code

cls
exit
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use [Mercurial source control](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) there is a nice tutorial at [Hg Init](http://hginit.com/).

Git is another option, but Mercurial is easier to use IMO.

You can get free, private source hosting for Mercurial at [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/).